# Summing weekly data in excel by dragging down formula

Tags: excel, date

Imagine the following excel worksheet:

I have consecutive dates in Column 'A' with 'A1' being the header 'Dates' and 'A2' being the first date, continuing indefinitely down the column.

In column 'B' I have my data values, with 'B1' being the header 'Value' and 'B2' being the first value of data, continuing indefinitely down the column.

In a separate worksheet I want to have the same header cells; 'Dates' in 'A1' and 'Value' in 'B1', but group my data weekly.

In cell 'A2' I have the first date, cell 'A3' contains the date one week later and so on. I can simply input the first two weekly start dates and then select both and drag down.

I attempted to use the following formula in 'B2' =SUM(Sheet1!B2:B8)

And this in 'B3' =SUM(Sheet1!B9:B15)

I then tried selecting both cells and dragging down, but it does not pick up on the 7 day increments in the formula for both the first cell and last cell in the range.

Why does this not work, how do I get Excel to correctly increase both the start and end cells in this formula by 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Home>Fill>Series and set step value to 7

Comment: This works fine for the date column, but I can't get the formula to sum at the correct intervals. I simply want it to sum B2:B8, B9:B15, B16:B22 etc.